# Lockscreen automatically relocks after unlock

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, smart-cover

**The Problem:** Sometimes, after a successful screen unlock, the device *immediately* relocks.

**Specifications:** Nexus 9, CyanogenMod 12-12.1, Android 5.0.1-5.1.1, pattern lock and Smart Lock > FaceUnlock and Location active, encryption active.

**Further details:** I also have a phone (Armani) that ran exactly the same settings from CM 12-12.1 and experienced no such problems. This is weird, especially that flounder is officially supported while armani is not. The problem comes, on average, every other day. I'd like to know if anyone else had experienced similar problems and what you did to resolve it. So far all that I had to do is to reboot the device - something that ain't so nice especially on an encrypted device.

Comment: Remove the lockscreen in the settings, lock your screen, unlock it again & add the previous lockscreen, see if that works

Comment: What is meant by remove the lockscreen in the settings? You mean set it to swipe?

Comment: There's a "none" option, select that.if there's not one, set to swipe. if that does not work, you can use adb to remove a lockscreen completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Trivial:** I found the answer... (Not the type of *Eureka!* thing, but kinda...)

I'm using this **Moko magnetic "smart"-cover** since the tablet came, and it was only recently I realized that it messes up with:

1. the Compass (guess what, it's a magnet) which then gave me the idea that it will mess with ...
2. The Lockscreen

If I folded the cover in a certain way even at the back of the device, then it will automatically lock. If I reorient the cover that the magnet is farther from the tablet, then no automatic locking occurs.

(Re-tagging this. Nothing to do with software.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Samsung Tab A 2019 Edition, that's how I fixed it:

1. Shutdown
2. Hold Vol Up and then Power on
3. It should say Secure Boot or sth like that
4. Log into your WLAN/WIFI/idkWhatItsCalled
5. Look for android updates and install if any
6. Edit Security Options or disable
7. Restart device